# Flex Flash sending a HTTP request with a dynamically creating url

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

Hi I've been connecting to my Server side code using HTTP Services.

However I'm stuck on something that I think must be very simple but I'm just not seeing it.

I create a session and the server response is as follows redirecting to

http://localhost:3000/users/126.xml which is exactly what I want.
However on the Flex side I don't know how to read this data into the application.

All previous requests have read the entire database into the applcation for example

returns all users.  But I just want user number 126 in this example.

The way I've been defining my http:services is as follows

but I need some way to write

But I can't figure out how to do that.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok This was a really dumb question - and figured it out as soon as I posted the question - I just needed to change the result format to e4x. Doh!

Comment: you can post this as answer, and accept it later (I think you need to wait a day or something) as an correct answer. Or you can delete this question, or flag it and ask for deletion, if you think it will not help anybody else.

Comment: +1 for solving your own problem

Answer (score 1):

Change the result format to e4x.